# Why is Cassandra creating a lot of threads?

Tags: cassandra

I have 3000 IOT devices which sends data to cassandra on every 10 sec. earlier cassandra service was getting exited(failed) every day. hence we increased server to 62 Gb RAM and 10TB hard disk. Now cassandra is getting exited(failed) almost after a week. I noticed taht cassandra has created 140 threads.

Why cassanda has created 140 threads? can I minimize thred count? is this a real reason of cassandra service getting failed?

please find atatched screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The number of threads spawned by Cassandra isn't necessarily a problem and isn't necessarily the reason for Cassandra failing.

In my experience, the number of threads on a node increase as the amount of application requests grows -- that is normal behaviour for multi-threaded applications like Cassandra.

You need to review the errors and warning messages in the Cassandra logs for clues as to why it is crashing. You also need to review your monitoring to see if the application load/traffic has increased.

Typically if a Cassandra node is overloaded, one of the symptoms is that it can no longer spawn threads because it has run out of resources. In this scenario, a high number of threads is just a symptom of the problem and not the cause. Cheers!

Comment: Thank your very much for your reply. I will definitely follow the instruction in order to catch the actual problem.

Comment: Happy to help. Please support the community by clicking **Watch tag** button on the `cassandra` tag. Cheers!