# How do we limit Cassandra's memory usage?

Tags: cassandra

I have cassandra installed on server which receives data from IOT devices at every 30 sec.
I was getting error in cassandra "OOM" (Out Of Memory). Hence I have increased the RAM and ROM of service and now again cassandra taking more and more memory which leading to same error again.

How can we limit cassandra to use defined memory? and what will be the consequence if we limit the memory?

Answer (score 2):

The `OutOfMemory` error is just a symptom of an underlying issue -- it isn't the problem that you should be focusing on.

As I've tried to explain in [your other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320368/), Cassandra is using resources to service requests. The more app requests a node needs to process, the more resources it will consume.

Threads get spawned when reading from or writing to the database and this consume resources such as CPU, memory, and disk IO. As a read or write request is processed by a node, the resources it use such as memory gets released back to the pool so it can be used by other threads. In a case where a node is overloaded, the available pool of resources get consumed quicker than what is available so it is not unexpected for a node to run into an `OutOfMemory` error.

You've provided very limited details in your question so it is difficult to know what is going on in your environment but if the nodes are indeed overloaded, the recommended approach is to increase the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes (horizontal scaling) to spread the load. Cheers!